# Download File in headless mode Chrome/Chromium Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, chromium

I am facing very strange problem while downloading the file in the headless mode using selenium Chrome webdriver in Python. I searched on google and find out a solution: to add below code and it must be working.

```
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_url}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

But while I add above code then It shows `Path too long: Failed Download.` 
[image]

But When I do not use the above code and also run the script without headless Then the same file downloads on the same path.

I wanted to run this script on a linux server and currently, it is working only without headless mode in my local PC. Can anyone help me how to download files using headless mode in Python?

Comment: try this:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/52425435/4513879

Comment: I have used the same code from same source

Comment: what's `download_url` in `'downloadPath': download_url`? is it the path where downloaded file should be saved or the source url for the download?

Comment: download path is  `D:/csvFiles`